# Day Light Savings and the way SQL Server 2008 and Oracle 91 takes care of it

Tags: sql-server-2008, oracle9i, dst

I am storing datetime field in UTC in both Oracle and SQL tables.
In my application,I need to convert from UTC to Local Time ,say Australia.

How can I do the same in both SQL and Oracle.

Is **Oracle and SQL Server automatically aware of history/future on DayLight savings time?**

*-Or we have to write specific procedures on both SQL and Oracle to correctly convert to the desired time based on Day Light Saving Options.*

I tried referring various articles,but none presents a clear view on the same.

Hope I can get a consolidated view here.